# Python's random module made inaccessible by Numpy's random module

Tags: python, numpy, random

When I call `random.sample(arr,length)`
an error returns `random_sample() takes at most 1 positional argument (2 given)`.  After some Googling I found out I'm calling Numpy's random sample function when I want to call the sample function of the random module.  I've tried importing numpy under a different name, which doesn't fix the problem.  I need Numpy for the rest of the program, though.

Any thoughts?  Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sounds like you have something like

```
import random
from numpy import *
```

and `random` is getting clobbered by the numpy import.  If you want to keep the `import *` then you'll need to rename `random`:

```
import random as rnd    # or whatever name you like
from numpy import *
```

Alternatively, and probably better, is to import numpy as a module instead of just yanking it all into your module's namespace:

```
import random
import numpy as np      # or leave as numpy, or whatever name you like
```

Answer (score 5):

This shouldn't happen. Check your code for bad imports like `from numpy import *`.

Comment: Yes, that was part of the problem.  Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Be sure to keep the imports distinct:

```
>>> import numpy.random
>>> import random         # python's random
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random as rd
```

Instead of:

`import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random`

Comment: You answered a 4-year old question with the same advice already in the other answers.  This doesn't add any value.